# Netbeans Swing Matisse JCombobox Key-Value Pair

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jcombobox, matisse

is there a way to set Key-Value String Map/Pair in JCombobox Netbeans Swing Matisse using GUI only ?
Below screenshot allow to insert single list
[image: JComboBox List Data]

but is there a way to insert Map/Key-Value String Pair using Matisse GUI instead of code like

```
Value - Display
_____   _____
ITEM1 - Item 1
ITEM2 - Item 2
ITEM3 - Item 3
ITEM4 - Item 4
```

as in HTML select option tag stored value and display value.

Comment: Can you explain further exactly what you are trying to acheive, teh answer could a yes or a no

Comment: @peeskillet please review , question updated .

Comment: So the display is the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So that why i am asking about using GUI not Code

Don't depend on an IDE to write/generate your code for you. The code will never be portable.

Maybe you can create a text file of all you key/value pairs. Then you create a simple routine that reads each file parses the data and adds a custom object to the ComboBoxModel.

For an example of such a custom object check out [Combo Box With Hidden Data](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/). It is a simple object that overrides the toString() method to display the value in the combo box.

And for those that suggest you should be using a custom Renderer, well they are only half right. Check out [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) which allows you to use a custom renderer without breaking the default functionality of the combo box.

Answer (score 1):

> " using GUI only ? "

I assume you mean from design view. I don't think so. Just hand code it. It's not that difficult.

Here's an example using a `Student` object as the map value, and the `Student` `id` as the map `key`. The `key` is the display value in the `JComboBox`. The value is retrieved from the selection by using `get(id)` from the map.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class MapCombo {

    public MapCombo() {
        Map<Integer, Student> map = createMap();
        JComboBox cbox = createComboBox(map);
        cbox.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Map ComboBox");
        frame.add(cbox);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Map<Integer, Student> createMap() {
        Map<Integer, Student> map = new HashMap<>();
        Student s1 = new Student(23, "Micheal Jordan");
        Student s2 = new Student(6, "Lebron James");
        Student s3 = new Student(3, "Chris Paul");
        Student s4 = new Student(8, "Kobe Briant");
        Student s5 = new Student(21, "Tim Duncan");

        map.put(s1.getId(), s1);
        map.put(s2.getId(), s2);
        map.put(s3.getId(), s3);
        map.put(s4.getId(), s4);
        map.put(s5.getId(), s5);

        return map;
    }

    private JComboBox createComboBox(final Map<Integer, Student> map) {
        final JComboBox cbox = new JComboBox();
        for (Integer id : map.keySet()) {
            cbox.addItem(id);
        }

        cbox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Integer id = (Integer)cbox.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println(map.get(id));
            }
        });

        return cbox;
    }

    public class Student {

        String name;
        Integer id;

        public Student(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Name: " + name + " - Stud ID: " + id;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MapCombo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i have lots of form with JCombobox (Key-Value)  . So that why i am asking about using GUI not Code .